# C# ASP.NET MVC: How to get list of elements by id column returned from a list in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have to create 2 lists and i am looking for the best practice and eventually oneline syntax!

I am using Entity Framework and I have 3 tables:

```
public class Position 
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Training 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Association 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Impact Impact { get; set; }

    public int TrainingId { get; set; }
    public virtual Training Training { get; set; }
    public int PositionId { get; set; }
    public virtual Position Position { get; set; }
}

public enum Impact 
{
    Optional,
    Mandatory
}
```

I have to select all the training which are mentioned in `Association` table as mandatory or optional (I mean that must have the column `Impact` fill with `Impact.Optional`) and the `PositionId` is the one that I give it through a parameter or something!

How can I do that?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Is this what you need? var result = db.Asociation.Where(x => x.Impact == Impact.YOUR_IMPACT && PositionId == YOUR_ID);

Comment: @Matt almost yes and with this, how I can get a collection of Training! Your syntax filters the right "associations" and I want to use `TrainingId` to take the training list!

Comment: Check my answer below and try again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
public List<Training> GetOptionalTrainings(int positionId)
{
  _context.Associations
    .Where(a => a.Impact == Impact.Optional && a.PositionId == positionId)
    .Select(a => a.Training)
    .ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

note that your relations are 1-1 ,Association will always have a Training , 
if you want a 0 or 1 relation you can change `public int TrainingId` to `public int? TrainingId`

*updated*